# PowerQuery M Folder import syntax for XML

Tags: xml, powerquery, m

I am unable to figure the correct syntax in M for getting a folder of xml files to load into my function.

These are 2 of my attempts that I cannot determine a way to resolve.

```
let ExcelFile = (FilePath, FileName) =>
let
    Source = Folder.Files(FilePath),
    Query1 = (FileName) => [FirstResult=Meeting(FileName), SecondResult=Race(FileName), ThirdResult=Reference(FileName), FourthResult=Horses(FileName)]
in
  ExcelFile
```

Example 2

```
let  xmlImport = (FilePath, FileName) =>
let
    Source = Folder.Files(FilePath),
    Query1 = (FileName) => [FirstResult=Meeting(FileName), SecondResult=Race(FileName), ThirdResult=Reference(FileName), FourthResult=Horses(FileName)],
    content = Binary.Combine(Source[Query1]),
    xmlImport = Xml.Tables(content)
in
    xmlImport
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you want to produce, but I can give a general example of what works, and a couple guesses why your Examples might be hitting errors?

---

Say my mashup starts like this:

```
let
    Source = Folder.Files("c:\code\css430\Final_Project\.idea")
in
    Source
```

And I want to load each cell as XML. First, I'll just click on one binary cell, and see what the UX auto-generates:

```
let
    Source = Folder.Files("c:\code\css430\Final_Project\.idea"),
    #"c:\code\css430\Final_Project\ idea\_misc xml" = Source{[#"Folder Path"="c:\code\css430\Final_Project\.idea\",Name="misc.xml"]}[Content],
    #"Imported XML" = Xml.Tables(#"c:\code\css430\Final_Project\ idea\_misc xml",null,1252),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Imported XML",{{"Attribute:version", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

The interesting bit is that `Xml.Tables` was called on the `[Content]` column. I'll delete the new steps, and add a custom column just for `Xml.Tables([Content])`:

```
let
    Source = Folder.Files("c:\code\css430\Final_Project\.idea"),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Xml", each Xml.Tables([Content]))
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

If you want to do more transformation than just call `Xml.Tables`, then add more steps after clicking on the one cell, copy the code, and delete the steps and put all the transformations into the `Table.AddColumn` function.

Only once you've got that all working, then refactor out the `FilePath` argument instead of the hard-coded file path.

---

Some things that might be going wrong in your examples:

Code like this:

```
(FilePath, FileName) =>
let
    Source = Folder.Files(FilePath),
    Query1 = (FileName) => ...
```

Means you're declaring two function that each have a parameter named `FileName`, which is just going to be confusing later. There are rules to define which parameter gets used, but it's best to just give them different names.

Calling `Xml.Tables` on top of `Binary.Combine` will almost always get you in trouble. If you copy-paste the text of two XML files it doesn't add up to a new XML file; it's going to be a format error. Always transform XML into M tables first, then combine those tables (e.g. `Table.Combine`). Binary combine works OK for combining plain-text and CSV binaries, but really only those types.

The code `Source[Query1]` looks like it will use the `Query1` function for something on the `Source` table, but it actually means find the `"Query1"` column of the table (which will cause an error). If you want to apply a transformation function to a table, `Table.AddColumn` is probably what you want, or maybe [`Table.TransformColumns`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt260818.aspx)

Comment: I have an XML file well many, i have chained together the 4 functions that extract the data from one xml file. I am now trying to take the 4 functions and make a folder query to process all xml files in the folder.